# PIE.js low performance

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, css3pie

I'm currently working on a plugin for automatical PIE attachment.
It goes through all the document CSS stylesheets, checks for CSS3 properties via indexOf, and then calls PIE attach method in case it founds any for the current selector.
The main loop goes like this:

```
    for (var j = 0, length2 = styleSheet.rules.length; j < length2; j++) {
      rule = styleSheet.rules[j];
      // the replacedProperties is a simple array
      // with string values for css properties - border-radius and so on
        $.each(replacedProperties, function(index, property) {
            if (rule.style.cssText.indexOf(property) !== -1) {
                try {
                    $(rule.selectorText).each(function() {
                       PIE.attach(this);
                    });

                 } catch(e) { }
                    return false;
                 }
            }

        });
    }
```

This is actually pretty slow, running up to 2s on a CSS3-heavy page in IE8 and IE7.
The question is, can I somehow improve the performance of this loop?
The PIE.js actually optimizes repeated attachment, so checking if the PIE was attached won't do anything.
And the standard detachment technique by $.fn.detach sadly doesn't work with PIE (though I haven't tried the vanilla version).
I would be extremely grateful for any answers.

Comment: WHY would you want to do that? PIE does that automatically. And i prefer `pie.htc`, this only triggers in IEs and is no additional request for the other browsers.

Comment: But it attaches itself only with PIE.attach, doesn't it?

Comment: The reason for it is to leave the designers and developers from the necessity to add classes for PIE attachment manually.

Comment: It doesn't automatically apply itself to all DOM elements.

Comment: Or I'm missing something from API.

Comment: I will post an answer, this is easier than using the limited space here in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read the docs, especially about pie.js: http://css3pie.com/documentation/pie-js/

Now I use `pie.htc` and besides having some disadvantages it hase more advantages so this is the preferrable solution.

You can define, which styles should be processed directly in the css - where it belongs by declaring `behaviour(/absolute-path-to-pie.htc);`. This is MUCH faster then iterating ALL the stylesheet and stylerules and THEN attaching pie. Also you can easily put this into a conditional stylesheet. I think this should pretty much solve your problems - no need to iterate over all styles manually.

Comment: But you still have to specify the behaviour for each existing element.

Comment: Attaching pie.js dinamically is much more flexible - you don't have to put this modernizing logic in css, you just have to add one simple plugin. It's just a matter of sacrificing performance for flexiblity.

Comment: Just add a line referencing pie.htc in your mixins for CSS, then when you include border radius it will just add in the apropriate CSS. If you use SASS you can just extend your class, making the CSS very minimal to achieve this.

Comment: well, i'm a fan of performance AND flexibility. And splitting the design logic and putting parts of it into some cryptic js is neither of those. Not to mention the horrible maintainability. with a well structured css this is easypeasy.

Comment: The problem is, we don't use mixins. Actually the decision of converting from pie.htc to pie.js was made not by me but by designer who asked me to come up with this plugin. So I'm just trying to make the best out of this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Big fan of PIE here. However, when it comes to performance, the cost is greater than one might imagine. Been recently developing a website on a monster PC so to speak, running Windows7 with IE8 and a few VM's for testing. Tested both PIE 1.0 and PIE 2.0 beta. Though early in the project, and with only a few dozen elements with PIE behavior attached, IE seems to choke on scroll-down, and when using jQueryUI effects and animations. With pie 2.0, turning off the polls, seems to improve performance, but defeats the purposes for which one uses pie in the first place... you get the desired visual appearance, but none of the effects. In the end, one needs to take into consideration the performance cost on the client side. In 2010, Google reported that almost 48% of the web clients were using IE mostly IE7(winXP). Though the numbers have changed much since, some simply don't have the means to upgrade. All things put together, delivering css3 content via PIE could have a big impact on the client... not knowing 100% how it will behave, your client could think twice before accessing your site because, it simply doesn't behave smooth(i know i would).
So, at least for this project. i'm dropping PIE, and reverting to the good old PNG. So far, the sprite containing the elements i needed to style with gradients and round corners is smaller than PIE. No doubt it will get larger, however it doesn't affect performance as before.
Just for the record, i don't know how browsers are built, nor do i really care, but man... they blew it big time with IE.